# Docker swarm : can't curl to a service container

Tags: docker, curl, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-network

I ve a service running under a stack swarm :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
de74ba4d48c1        myregistry/myApi:1.0  "java -Dfile.encodin…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        8300/tcp            myApiCtn
```

As you can see , my service is running on the 8300 port.

The probleme is that when i run curl ; it seems to not reply:

```
[user@server home]$ curl http://localhost:8300/api/elk/batch
```

> curl: (52) Empty reply from server

In another side if i ran my container manually (without stack and without swarm services ) 
(docker run ...)

**->** curl works well

My **docker-compose** is the following :

```
---
version: '3.4'
services:
  api-batch:
    image: myRegistry/myImageApi
    networks:
      - net_common
      - default
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
    - /opt/application/current/logs:/opt/application/current/logs
    - /var/opt/data/flat/flf/:/var/opt/data/flat/flf/
    tty: true
    ports:
      - target: 8300
        published: 8300
        protocol: tcp
    deploy:
      mode: global
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1024M      
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.type == test
    healthcheck:
      disable: true
networks:
  net_common:
    external: true
```

Where my networks list is the following :

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                   DRIVER              SCOPE
17795bfee9ca        bridge                 bridge              local
0faecb070730        docker_gwbridge        bridge              local
51c34d251495        host                   host                local
j2nnf26asn3k        ingress                overlay             swarm
3all3tmn3qn9        net_common             overlay             swarm
b7alw2yi5fk9        srcd-current_default   overlay             swarm
```

**Any suggestion to make it work under swarm service ?**

Comment: Can you share your docker compose?

Comment: @Hadi i ve attached my docker-compose file

Comment: Do you also link it to the `net_common` network when it works?

Comment: @MartinvanWingerden yes it's an overlay network (i ve added that trace to my question )

Comment: please also share your service log whit this command `docker service logs api-batch`

Comment: why you use `default` network? if you don't need that, remove from your docker compose.

Comment: Try hitting the IP of the machine (that you used as a listen/advertise address when you init/joined the Swarm), that's where it will be listening. It's different from when you just type `docker run...`.